# Is it possible to inhibit font-locking for a specific buffer region?

Tags: emacs, customization, jit, font-lock

In a follow-up question to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592024/font-lock-and-disable-js2-mode-parsing-node-shebang-line), is it possible to inhibit font-locking for a specific region in a buffer?  I've looked through the special text properties portion of the manual, but couldn't find any properties that appeared to disable fontification.  Is there another mechanism?

As an example, could font-lock be disabled for just the first line or two of a buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no specific support for that, no.

You can try to abuse the `font-lock-extend-region-functions`, but you'll need to be extra careful to try and avoid inf-loops where one `font-lock-extend-region-function` tries to extend the region and you shrink it back ad-nauseam.